# Reference a cell in the previous visible row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

How can I reference a cell in the same column in the previous visible row from a filtered range?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is very easy **if we prepare to do it.**

Say we have data like:

[image]

The first step is to introduce a "helper" column.  In **E2** we enter:

```
=IF(SUBTOTAL(3,A2:A2)=0,MIN($E$1:E1)-1,SUBTOTAL(3,$A$2:$A2))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Now the cool thing about the "helper" column is that no matter how you filter it, it always shows a simple sequential sequence....let's filter for *Alice*

[image]

This means that any cell can:

1. retrieve the value in column **E**
2. subtract **1** from it
3. use this value in a *Index()/Match()* formula to retrieve any value in the previous visible row

**EDIT#1:**

To answer your question, in **C5** we enter:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$21,MATCH(E5-1,$E$2:$E$21,0))
```

and with no filtering **C5** will display **$391.00**
But with *Alice* filtering **C5** will display **$446.00**

Comment: I tried to use Index/Match, but without a success, how can I find the coordinates of the above cell? For example, in your last image, imagine that c5 needs a reference to its above cell, in this case c2